# PHP CURL Never Ending Request

Tags: php, curl

I recently uploaded my project from localhost to a live hosting server. In my project I have used a CURL request, which worked absolutely fine on localhost up til now.

As soon as I moved it on live server (Arizonawebservices.com), that CURL request stopped working. When my page sends the CURL request, it keeps on processing and never returns any output.

I checked server for CURL support (using "which curl" command in PHP's exec() function), and yes it has CURL support enabled.

Also created a test page for manually shooting CURL requests and check if it works ok. Tried www.google.com, www.yahoo.com, and many other URLs, all are working fine, but when I put my original API URL "https://dataviz.sandbox.rcoanalytics.com:10105/oauth/token" in it. It starts behaving like before. I am completely unable to get any response from that CURL request. Any help would be appreciated.

Used following code for testing purpose:

```
function httpPost($url,$params)
{

   $postData = '';

   if (!empty($params)) {
    //create name value pairs seperated by &
    foreach($params as $k => $v) 
    { 
       $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
    }
    $postData = rtrim($postData, '&');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    if ($postData != "") {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    }

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    if($output === false)
    {
        echo "Error Number:".curl_errno($ch)."<br>";
        echo "Error String:".curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

}

$params = array(

);

echo httpPost("https://dataviz.sandbox.rcoanalytics.com:10105/oauth/token", $params);
```

Comment: Are you using command line CURL (because you checked the command line) or php's curl library?

Comment: Used both methods.

Answer (score 2):

The url has an SSL error, so in the cURL request when cURL tries to verify the host it blocks you from accessing the address.

[image]

use the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

This is obviously **insecure** method to access the URL but for a host like this one it will do the trick.

Comment: added your 2 lines as well, no luck yet.

Comment: page keeps on spinning, i think curl needs to finish its request before displaying any errors. in my case it seems like it's never going to complete.

Comment: I ran your code from the command line as well as from the browser.. It runs fine

Comment: yeah, it was working good on my localhost, it all happened when i put it live

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138631/discussion-between-shakti-phartiyal-and-ali).